# How shall I fill out the "business" information in 1040 schedule C for working as an independent contractor?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I received some payment in cash for being an independent contractor for a company for a 2-month period in 2016.

I searched on Google, and it seems that I should file [1040 schedule C](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0tYjAza3TAhXGSCYKHQ0wB-AQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.irs.gov%2Fpub%2Firs-pdf%2Ff1040sc.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGGLz14MnOzWt3hULMhqG4FJMKyzw&sig2=ZjyUrm-25WaW1cBxlDrwig) to report the payment.

Schedule C is for profit and loss of business. 
How shall I fill out

- "Name of proprietor", (shall I write my name here?)
- "Social security number (SSN)",  (shall I write my SSN here?)
- Box A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, and J, (shall I write the company's info here?)

which look to me are for a business, while I was an independent contractor?

Does "business" referred in Schedule C mean me or the company?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are the proprietor of the business and your SSN is listed on Schedule C. The information on Schedule C is for *your* unincorporated business as a contractor; it is a sole proprietorship. You might choose to do this business under your own name e.g. Tim Taylor (getting paid with checks made out to Tim Taylor) or a modified name such as Tim the Tool Man Taylor (this is often referred to as DBA - Doing Business as), under a business name such as Tool Time etc. with business address being your home address or separate premises, and checking accounts to match etc. and all that is what the IRS wants to know about on Schedule C.  Information about the company that *paid* you is not listed on Schedule C.